# How can I set the limit of NFTs that can be minted per wallet?

Tags: solana, metaplex

I need to update the limit of how many NFTs can be minted on 1 wallet

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using the current Candy Machine v2 Program you cant set (for public mint) a limit of NFTs per wallet.

How can this be solved? You can use whitelist Settings to make sure how many NFTs can be minted per wallet. Why? Because with whitelist settings any person who has the SPL token can mint while she/he hold the whitelist Token.

So to have a limit per wallet you have to set [whitelist settings](https://docs.metaplex.com/candy-machine-v2/configuration#whitelist-settings) with `"mode" : { "burnEveryTime": true }` and to distribute the whitelist tokens you can use [gumdrop](https://docs.metaplex.com/airdrops/create-gumdrop)

Other way (more complex) is grabbing the [CandyMachinev2 rust program](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/tree/master/candy-machine/program/src) and adapt it to ensure a limit per wallet using an PDA per wallet. Then deploy ur new CMv2 program to solana network and use the new program id in ur CLI and mint page

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use gumdrop for this.

Go through Metaplex docs for gumdrop. Gumdrop can be also used to mint NFTs and it has a feature distribution list of selected users and you can define amount of NFTs distributed per user.
It can be one for each or random for each user.

[Gumdrop Docs](https://docs.metaplex.com/guides/airdrops)

[Whitelist Mint using gumdrop](https://hackmd.io/@epomatti/B1kUsyEhF)